# Object referring to the object running a specific piece of code in Game Maker

Tags: object, game-maker

Java Script has it's `this.property` in it's constructor functions to access the variables of that object such as `this.y` or `this.x`. Is there an easy way to do this in game maker without going through a process if gathering the instance id?

I'm trying to draw a button at the position of a specific object, but that button appears in multiple spots on the screen. I tried `draw_button(instance.x, instance.y, instance.x+100, instance.y+30, false)`, but that throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Each instance has own name. *Room Editor* -> RMB on instance -> *Copy Instance Name* (or also *Rename Object Instance*). Then you can refer the instance using that name.

If you create button using code, but not Room Editor, then you can store `id` of "parent", like:

```
/// Create event of your object
var btn = instance_create(x, y, obj_button);
btn.parent = id;
```

Button's `Draw` event:

```
draw_button(parent.x, parent.y, parent.x + 100, parent.y + 100, true);
```